# How can I install and use (mice) function in R?

Tags: r, r-mice

I want to use mice function to handle the missing data that I have in (data). I installed the package and I called the library. However, when I am trying to apply the function to my data it gives me error as below:

> (Error in mice(data[, 5:9], m = 3, seed = 123) : 
>      could not find function "mice")

I have a normal data frame that includes NAs

```
install.packages('mice')
library(mice)
library(VIM)
md.pattern(data)
md.pairs(data)
My_New_Data <- mice(data[,5:9], m=3, seed=123)
```

I am expecting the function to solve the problem and replace the NAs with reasonable values. It did not work at all!

## Edit (incorporating comment suggestion)

In the comments the running `mice::mice(data[, 5:9], m = 3, seed = 123)`. I ran this and the following error was returned.

> **Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):**
>
> lazy-load database 'C:/Users/MUSTAFA KAMAL/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom/R/broom.rdb' is corrupt
>
> **In addition:**
>
> Warning message: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: Did it install without an error?

Comment: It seems like the package didn’t load.  It would help if you ran each line one at a time, then copy any errors/warnings to your post.

Comment: mice::mice(data[,5:9], m = 3, seed = 123)  is it work?

Comment: Joe, no the installation is without errors.

Comment: Dear Joe this is the error that I am getting when running mice: (Error in mice(data[, 5:9], m = 3, seed = 123) : 
  could not find function "mice")

Comment: Dear Kim, thanks! when I tried your peace of code it returns the following error (Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/MUSTAFA KAMAL/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom/R/broom.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1)

Comment: @MustafaAttallah, it seems you are running `R-3.5.x`. I'd suggest updating to `R-3.6.x` from cran.  Your error might simply be a new update being incompatible with an old package. The `installr` package has an `updateR` function which can be used. If the error persists i suggest `remove.packages("broom"); install.packages("broom")`, as this package seems to be the problem.

Comment: @MustafaAttallah I'm glad i could help. I have added the comment as a more explicit answer. Since  `R-3.6.0` this issue seems to have been slightly more prevalent on SO. If the answer seems explicit enough, i suggest marking it as an answer, to improve visibility for others with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In order to incorporate an answer to this question, I will rewrite my comment which resolved the problem, in the form of a short answer.

From the comments executing `mice::mice(data[, 5:9], m = 3, seed = 123)` resulted in an error message, showing the directory `~/Documents/R/win-library/**3.5**/broom/R/broom.rdb` being corrupt.

From the corrupted directory path, one can see that OP was running `R-3.5.x`, while the newest version is `R-3.6.x`. Some packages updated since the most recent R-update has experienced similar problems, as such a first step towards solving these types of issues is updating `R`. The `installr` contains the function `updateR` which can help smooth over such updates, while also updating any outdated packages.

As a side note, an update sometimes fails to update the actual packages or results in other packages being corrupted, as such if an error persists one solution is to simply delete and re-install the package (or the entire `~/Documents/R/win-library/3.z/` directory). In the question from OP the corrupt package is the `broom` package, as such one could re-install this package by running

```
remove.packages("broom")
install.packages("broom")
```

which should resolve any leftover issues. Note however multiple packages might be corrupt, and likely only one will be shown every time the function is executed. In such cases a full package clear will do the trick, but requires re-installing all packages. For this one can export all installed packages prior to removing them all, by noting that a full list of installed packages is contained in `installed.packages()`, which can then be exported to a file with for example `write.table` or `write.csv`.